# mongodump a db on archlinux

Tags: mongodb, archlinux, mongodump

I try to backup my local mongodb. I use archlinux and installed mongodb-tools in order to use mongodump.
I tried :

```
mongodump --host localhost --port 27017 
mongodump --host localhost --port 27017 --db mydb
```

Every time I have the same response :

```
Failed: error connecting to db server: no recheable server
```

I'm however able to connect to the database using

```
mongo --host localhost --port 27017
```

or just

```
mongo
```

My mongodb version is 3.0.7.
I did not set any username/password

How can I properly use mongodump to backup my local database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the `mongodump` tool, see this [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-620) ticket for more detail. You should be able to use `mongodump` if you explicitely specify the IP address:

```
mongo --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017
```

Comment: Damn. I have to wait then

Comment: @NielsRobin-Aubertin Why that? "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" should be interchangeable. If you only got the host name, simply resolve it and use the resulting IP. Although hard coding the IP makes sense here, since it isn't really likely to change any time soon that "localhost" resolves to "127.0.0.1"

Answer (score 1):

"Properly" is a highly subjective term in this context. To give you an impression:

mongodump and mongorestore aren't incredibly fast. In sharded environments, they can take *day**s*** (note the plural!) for reasonably sized databases. Which in turn means that in a worst case scenario, you can loose days worth of data. Furthermore, during backup, the data may change quite a bit, so the state of your backup may be inconsistent. It is better to think of mongodump as "mongodumb" in this aspect.
Your application has to be able to deal with the lack of consistency gracefully, which can be quite a pain in the neck to develop. Furthermore, long restore times cost money and (sometimes even more important) reputation.

I personally use mongodump only in two scenarios: for backing up a sharded clusters metadata (which is only a couple of MB in size) and for (relatively) cheap data, which is easy to reobtain by other means.

For doing a MongoDB backup properly, imho, there are only three choices:

1. MongoDB Inc's cloud backup,
2. MongoDB Ops Manager
3. Filesystem snapshots

### [Cloud backup](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/)

It has several advantages. You can do point in time recoveries, guaranteeing to have the database in a consistent state as it was at the chosen point in time. It is extremely easy to set up and maintain.
However, you guessed it, it comes with a price tag based on data volatility and overall size, which, imho, is reasonable for small to medium sized data with low to moderate volatility.

### [MongoDB Ops Manager](https://www.mongodb.com/products/ops-manager)

Being an on premise version of the cloud backup (It has quite some other features out of the scope of this answer, too), it offers the same benefits. It is more suited for upper scale medium size to large databases or for databases with disproportionate high volatility (as indicated by a high "OplogGb/h" value in comparison to the data size).

### Filesystem snapshots

Well, it is sort of cheap. Just make a snapshot, mount it, copy it to some backup space, unmount and destroy the snapshot, optionally compress the copied data and you are done. There are some caveats, though.

#### Synchronization

To get a backup of consistent data, you need to synchronize your snapshots on a sharded cluster. Especially since the sharded clusters metadata needs to be consistent with the backups, too, if you want a halfway fast recovery. That can become a bit tricky. To make sure your data is consistent, you'd need to disconnect all `mongos`, stop the balancer, fsync the data to the files on each node, make the snapshot, start the balancer again and restart all `mongos`. To have this *properly* synced, you need a maintenance window of some minutes every time you make a backup.

Note that for a simple replica set, synchronization is not required and backups work flawlessly.

#### Overprovisioning

Filesystem snapshots work with what is called "Copy-On-Write" (CoW). A bit simplified: When you make a snapshot and a file is modified, it is instead copied and the changes are applied to the newly copied file. The snapshot however, points to the old file. It is obvious that in order to be able to make a snapshot, as per CoW, you need some additional disk space so that MongoDB can work while you deal with the snapshot. Let us assume a worst case scenario in which all the data is changed – you'd need to overprovision your partition for MongoDB by at least 100% of your data size or, to put it in other terms, your critical disk utilization would be 50% minus some threshold for the time you need to scale up. Of course, this is a bit exaggerated, but you get the picture.

### Conclusion

IMHO, proper backups should be done this way:

- mongorestore for cheap data and little concern for consistency
- Filesystem snapshots for replica sets
- Cloud Backups for small to medium sized sharded databases with low to moderate volatility
- Ops Manager Backups for large databases or small to medium ones with disproportionate high volatility

As said: "properly" is a highly subjective term when it comes to backups. ;)

Comment: For now, the "proper" answer was @jaco's one. But I will keep your answer in mind for the future